Guess the reference!
My name is user5127! I have a friend named (encrypted) Q2hyaXN0b3BoZXI=! He told me this:

Never lie!
It's gonna take you thousand years to fix your car.
I'll happily give you some coffee to drink.
You're so sweet; you are like a flower.
An airplane goes flying up, up, and away!

He says he is referencing something!
What is it, and how did you find out?
--user5127
Extra credit: Find the name of the friend from the encrypted data and tell me how!
Hint:

 He is referencing a song.


Not really sure the hint is necessary. Both the puzzle and the encryption of the name are quite easy by the standards of this site.

@kagami Should I remove the hint? I showed it to some friends who found it difficult and couldn't solve it

@kagami then post an answer!

Maybe change "you are so sweet..." to "you're so sweet..." ?

The song is...

 A rick roll!


 Take the first word of the first sentence, second word of the second, etc.

Your friend's name is

 Christopher

Encoded with

 Base 64


That was fast! Next time I'll try to make a harder one
